# How to get Facebook API caller class and use them?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql

**Please don't avoid this post.**
I am trying to find Facebook caller class name.

I'm searching something like below example class on developer Facebook.

example:
'fb_api_caller_class' => `'com.facebook.registration.protocol.RegisterAccountMethod'`
'fb_api_req_friendly_name' => `'registerAccount'`
'method' => `'user.register'`

caller class are:
`com.facebook.registration.protocol.RegisterAccountMethod`
        `registerAccount`
        `user.register`

How to I find them and use them?

Give me tips, trick and example please. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

No one help you... They don't know how to find it and use it.
Contact with expert  facebook graph api developer. stackoverflow ask you question again and again. they don't give you this type solution. all the beat.